# TestNg @Dataprovider is not working in my DataDriven testing - using selenium eclipse

Tags: selenium, testng, dataprovider, testng-dataprovider, testng-annotation-test

My Java class is not running.
I have a @DataProvider with Apache POI to read data from an Excel file and set that values in an web page. but the script is ending with No test found error. Here is my code :

```
package testCases;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


import base.TestBase;

public class StudentRegistrationForm extends TestBase {

    
    @Test(dataProvider = "getData")
    public void addStudent(String fname, String email, String CurrentAddress,String PermAddress) {
        

        System.setProperty("org.uncommons.reportng.escape-output", "false");
        //driver.get(confg.getProperty("testsiteurl"));
        driver.get(confg.getProperty("url2"));
        log.debug("Navigated to : " + confg.getProperty("url2"));
        
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(or.getProperty("fullname"))).sendKeys(fname);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(or.getProperty("email"))).sendKeys(email);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(or.getProperty("currentAddress"))).sendKeys(CurrentAddress);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(or.getProperty("permAddress"))).sendKeys(PermAddress);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(or.getProperty("submit"))).click();
        log.debug("Completed Test 2 - Student Registration Form");
        Reporter.log("Completed Test 2 - Student Registration Form");
    }

    @DataProvider(name="getData")
    public Object[][] getData(){
        
            String SheetName = "sheet1";
    
            int rows = excel.getRowCount(SheetName);
            int cols = excel.getColumnCount(SheetName);
    
            Object[][] data = new Object[rows - 1][cols];
    
            for (int RowNum = 2; RowNum < rows; RowNum++) {
                for (int colNum = 0; colNum < cols; colNum++) {
                    data[RowNum - 2][colNum] = excel.getCellData(SheetName, colNum, RowNum);
                }
            }
        return data;
    }
}
```

And here is my output in the eclipse console.

## ===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

## ===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 0, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

[TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run
Usage:  [options] The XML suite files to run
Options:
-alwaysrunlisteners
Should MethodInvocation Listeners be run even for skipped methods
Default: true
-configfailurepolicy
Configuration failure policy (skip or continue)
-d
Output directory
-dataproviderthreadcount
Number of threads to use when running data providers
-dependencyinjectorfactory
The dependency injector factory implementation that TestNG should use.
-excludegroups
Comma-separated list of group names to  exclude
-failwheneverythingskipped
Should TestNG fail execution if all tests were skipped and nothing was
run.
Default: false
-groups
Comma-separated list of group names to be run
-junit
JUnit mode
Default: false
-listener
List of .class files or list of class names implementing ITestListener
or ISuiteListener
-methods
Comma separated of test methods
Default: []
-methodselectors
List of .class files or list of class names implementing IMethodSelector
-mixed
Mixed mode - autodetect the type of current test and run it with
appropriate runner
Default: false
-objectfactory
List of .class files or list of class names implementing
ITestRunnerFactory
-parallel
Parallel mode (methods, tests or classes)
Possible Values: [tests, methods, classes, instances, none, true, false]
-port
The port
-reporter
Extended configuration for custom report listener
-spilistenerstoskip
Comma separated fully qualified class names of listeners that should be
skipped from being wired in via Service Loaders.
Default: 
-suitename
Default name of test suite, if not specified in suite definition file or
source code
-suitethreadpoolsize
Size of the thread pool to use to run suites
Default: 1
-testclass
The list of test classes
-testjar
A jar file containing the tests
-testname
Default name of test, if not specified in suitedefinition file or source
code
-testnames
The list of test names to run
-testrunfactory, -testRunFactory
The factory used to create tests
-threadcount
Number of threads to use when running tests in parallel
-threadpoolfactoryclass
The threadpool executor factory implementation that TestNG should use.
-usedefaultlisteners
Whether to use the default listeners
Default: true
-log, -verbose
Level of verbosity
-xmlpathinjar
The full path to the xml file inside the jar file (only valid if
-testjar was specified)
Default: testng.xml

Comment: Does your test work without data provider?

Comment: Yes , I can run without data provider

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the testng usage in your code above.  This simply means there is no data being provided by the data provider.  You can either put a debug point on your data object or print it to see if the data array is being initialized.  Maybe your excel utility is not correctly written or an exception is being eaten inside.

Comment: sure thanks for the comment